How can I see how many concurrent viewers a YouTube stream had after the stream ended?
How can I see how many concurrent viewers a YouTube stream had after the stream ended? I'm not the stream owner. The total number of views is different from the number of
concurrent viewers a YouTube stream had.

Is the API an option?

@Laurel thanks, yes
